# $p$-adic number field $\mathbb{Q}_p $and algebraic numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic

As we all know, the complex number field $\mathbb{C}$ be a finite Galois extension field of the real number field that contains all algebraic numbers.
I want to know the proof of the following proposition:
Any p-adic number field $\mathbb{Q}_p$  has a finite Galois extension field $E$ such that $E$ contains $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.
In addition, what is the relationship between the complex number field and the algebraic closed of  $\mathbb{Q}_p$?
Is there an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$, it can be embedded into $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and can be embedded into the real number field? If the answer is yes, is there the largest such field?

Comment: The question is not clear to me.  There is no finite algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$.  There is no such thing as an intersection of $\mathbb Q_p$ and the real numbers, because they do not lie in a common field.  I'm not sure what relationship between the complex numbers and $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$ you would expect; they're isomorphic, anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your  answer. I'm very sorry I didn't make my question clear.  Your last sentence  means that the complex numbers field $C$ and  $\overline{\mathbb{Q} }$ is isomorphic ? This is a surprising fact.

Comment: The complex numbers and the algebraic closure of the p-adic numbers are isomorphic as fields. But not with the algebraic closure of the rationals.

Comment: For every finite extension $K$ of $\mathbf{Q}_p$, there exists $n_0$ such that for every $n\ge n_0$, there does not exist any $x\in K$ such that $x^n=p$. Hence the set of $\mathbf{Q}$-algebraic elements  in $K$ is not algebraically closed. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @YCor Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to answer what it seems you ask.

About your last question: "Is there an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$, such that it can be embedded into $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and it can be embedded into the real number field? If the answer is yes, is there the largest such field?"

If you consider **algebraic** extensions, then for any prime number $p$ there is the so called maximal totally $p$-adic extension, formed by the algebraic numbers (in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$) whose irreducible polynomial splits in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. It is an extension of infinite degree. It can be seen as the maximal algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ inside $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

One can also take the intersection (inside $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$) of the maximal totally $p$-adic extensions for some primes and also of the totally real algebraic numbers (which satisfy the analogous property to "totally $p$-adic" but for the real field), and if you intersect finitely many of them the result is still an infinite algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

If you consider arbitrary subfields of the real numbers and of the $p$-adic numbers, as already said, you cannot even compare them since there is no "natural" field containing both ($p$-adic and reals).

About the proof of the proposition you want to know, I am sorry to say that there is no such proof as the proposition you stated is false. One has that for any $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$, there is no finite extension containing $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: Elaborating on "no 'natural' field" (for the asker's benefit; of course you know): there is a field abstractly containing $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q_p$, namely $\mathbb C$, in the sense that it admits homomorphic embeddings from both (non-uniquely for $\mathbb Q_p$); but there is no topological field containing $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q_p$, in the sense that it admits continuous homomorphic embeddings from both, since $p^n \to \infty$ in $\mathbb R$ but $p^n \to 0$ in $\mathbb Q_p$.

Comment: Elaborating on "there is no finite extension containing $\overline{\mathbb Q}$" (again, for the asker's benefit):   an extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ containing an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$ would in particular contain every $\sqrt[n]p$, but $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt[n]p)$ is of degree $n$ over $\mathbb Q_p$ for every positive integer $n$.

Comment: @LSpice I agree that $\mathbb{C}$ contains (a lot of) fields isomorphic (as a field) to $\mathbb{Q}_p$, but there is no 'natural' embedding of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ inside $\mathbb{C}$. To show there is the embedding you almost sure need to use the axiom of choice, so there is not a constructive one.

Comment: [Certainly](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419182/p-adic-number-field-q-p-and-algebraic-numbers/419204#comment1076452_419204); I don't know whether the embedding requires the axiom of choice, but I'm sure someone does, and possibly has explained it here on MO!  I did not mean to disagree with you, only to elaborate. \\ Also, in [my prior comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419182/p-adic-number-field-q-p-and-algebraic-numbers/419204#comment1076442_419204), please read "an extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ containing an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$" rather than "… of $\mathbb Q_p$".

Comment: In fact, you are right. It has been explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338148/is-there-an-explicit-embedding-from-the-various-fields-of-p-adic-numbers-mathb?noredirect=1&lq=1) that you really need the axiom of choice.